# Not able to begin "External Testing"—iTunes Connect resets to "Not available for testing"

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, beta

I have my external testers setup, my build uploaded and "Ready to test," and when I click "Start testing" on the iTunes Connect "External Testing" page, everything appears to be fine.

However, when I reload the page, my build has been unselected and "Not Available For Testing" has been reselected instead. Also, my testers aren't receiving the email! Any quick advice on this would be terrific, thanks for reading.

(Also, my app is big, over 200 MB. But, I've run betas before with no problem before the iTunes Connect redesign.)

Comment: apple knows about the issue. just wait for them to fix it................................is it fixed yet? probably not.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Do you have a link to any more information?

Comment: I've spoken with apple about trying to add itunesconnect users to team for testing. This seems like a different but connected problem. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/170341/cannot-seem-to-add-internal-testers-with-existing-itunes-connect-accounts. 1(800) 633-2152 is Apple Developer Customer Service

Comment: I am having the same problem.  It automatically goes into "Not Available For Testing"

Comment: So far I've tried creating a new provisioning profile, uploading with and without bitcode, using XCode and Application Loader… still no luck!

Comment: Same problem, and as usual, their useless system status page is all green: https://developer.apple.com/system-status/

Comment: @Rogare any info about this I am also facing the same issue. It is automatically going to  “Not available for testing” status.

Comment: Just got off the phone with Apple and this is indeed a "known issue." I'll be sending them some more information to help troubleshoot, and will be sure to update this page when I get more info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be resolved. No changes at all on my end, but this time after pressing "Start testing" it actually works. My beta invitations were sent out successfully. (I later heard back from Apple who confirmed it was a problem on their end. Quite good custom support.)

Answer (score 3):

It's ok now. It seems FlightTest service is not work until yesterday, but it's working fine now, you can try again!
BTW, mail naming of the letters have to all lower case, not including any upper case and fill to what to test/app description textfield by your pre-release app.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, here it goes when it came and how it got resolved,

1 -- It happens when my **Apple ID password changed**

Then all of sudden, I am keep getting this message, if I tried to download any app from TestFlight account,

To resolve that, I resent the intuition and redeemed again, and problem gone!